# Create smart folder with Swift

Tags: macos, swift

Is there a possibility to write code that creates a smart folder? I would want my application to create a smart folder which shows all files belonging to Microsoft. I can create it easly myself from the finder but could this be made with Swift as well?

Comment: A smart folder where? In the Finder?

Comment: Lets say on the desktop. I would need the information in this folder. Date, Name etc...

Comment: In that case, I would use AppleScript to tell the Finder what to do.